# drop all databases at the same time

Tags: python, mysql

I want to drop all of my databases at the same time and I have done this function so far but unfortunately, it doesn't work and gives me no error at all nothing.

```
import mysql.connector


def drop_database():
    print('CONNECTING ...')

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="xxx",
        user="xxx",
        password="xxx",
        port='xxx'
    )

    print('CONNECTED')

    # database_list = []

    drop_command = 'drop database'
    show_databases = 'SHOW DATABASES;'
    my_cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
    my_cursor.execute(show_databases)
    for show_databases in my_cursor:
        my_cursor.execute(drop_command, str(show_databases[0]), ';')

    for show_databases in my_cursor:
        print(show_databases[0])

    mydb.commit()
    mydb.close()


drop_database()
```

Comment: You’re attempting to iterate over `my_cursor` twice which is probably not going to work.

Comment: but the first one should be ok, am I right?